# Nanomsg non-blocking bidirectional socket with multi-threaded application

Tags: c++, sockets, nonblocking, nanomsg

I'm using Nanomsg to do IPC in my system using C++. I want to create a background thread to handle the message both send and recv. I use pair paradigm and I use nn_poll to check if the socket fd is writable or readable, if readable then read; if writable then pop one item from message queue and send. My problem is the backgroudn thread I create is using to much CPU usage since there is no sleep in nn_poll loop, is there any way to reduce the CPU usage but still make the latency like there is no sleep? Below are my example code. Thanks.

Server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <mutex>
#include <nanomsg/pair.h>
#include <nanomsg/nn.h>

class Nanomsg {
private:
    bool _server;
    bool _stop;

    int _sock;
    std::string _url;
    std::thread _th;
    std::queue<std::string> _queue;

    std::mutex _queueMutex;

    void _start() {
        _sock = nn_socket(AF_SP, NN_PAIR);

        if (_sock < 0) {
            std::cout << "failed to create socket" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        int rc = 0;

        if (_server) {
            rc = nn_bind(_sock, _url.c_str());
        } else {
            rc = nn_connect(_sock, _url.c_str());
        }

        if (rc < 0) {
            std::cout << "failed to connect/bind socket" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        struct nn_pollfd pfd{};
        pfd.fd = _sock;
        pfd.events = NN_POLLIN | NN_POLLOUT;

        while (!_stop) {
            std::cout << "ssasd" << std::endl;
            rc = nn_poll(&pfd, 1, 2000);

            if (rc == 0) {
                std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }

            if (rc == -1) {
                std::cout << "error!" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            if (pfd.revents & NN_POLLIN) {
                char *buf = nullptr;
                int rbs = nn_recv(_sock, &buf, NN_MSG, 0);

                if (rbs < 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                std::string r(buf, rbs);

                std::cout << "received [" << r << "]" << std::endl;

                nn_freemsg(buf);
            }

            if (pfd.revents & NN_POLLOUT) {
                std::cout << "asd" << std::endl;
                if (_queue.empty()) {
                    continue;
                }

                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queueMutex);
                    auto msg = _queue.front();

                    std::cout << "send [" << msg << "]" << std::endl;

                    rc = nn_send(_sock, msg.c_str(), msg.length(), 0);
                    if (rc >= 0) {
                        _queue.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

public:
    Nanomsg() : _sock(0), _server(false), _stop(false), _url("ipc:///tmp/test.ipc") {

    }

    Nanomsg(std::string url, bool server) : _url(std::move(url)), _sock(0), _server(server), _stop(false) {

    }

    void start() {
        _th = std::thread([=]() {
            _start();
        });
    }

    void stop() {
        _stop = true;

        if (_th.joinable()) {
            _th.join();
        }
    }

    void send(const std::string& msg) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queueMutex);
            _queue.push(msg);
        }
    }

};

int main() {

    Nanomsg server("ipc:///tmp/test.ipc", true);

    server.start();

    while (true) {
        server.send("test");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <mutex>
#include <nanomsg/pair.h>
#include <nanomsg/nn.h>

struct nn_pollf {
    int fd;
    short events;
    short revents;
};

class Nanomsg {
private:
    bool _server;
    bool _stop;

    int _sock;
    std::string _url;
    std::thread _th;
    std::queue<std::string> _queue;

    std::mutex _queueMutex;

    void _start() {
        _sock = nn_socket(AF_SP, NN_PAIR);

        if (_sock < 0) {
            std::cout << "failed to create socket" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        int rc = 0;

        if (_server) {
            rc = nn_bind(_sock, _url.c_str());
        } else {
            rc = nn_connect(_sock, _url.c_str());
        }

        if (rc < 0) {
            std::cout << "failed to connect/bind socket" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        struct nn_pollfd pfd{};
        pfd.fd = _sock;
        pfd.events = NN_POLLIN | NN_POLLOUT;

        while (!_stop) {
            std::cout << "ssasd" << std::endl;
            rc = nn_poll(&pfd, 1, 2000);

            if (rc == 0) {
                std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }

            if (rc == -1) {
                std::cout << "error!" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            if (pfd.revents & NN_POLLIN) {
                char *buf = nullptr;
                int rbs = nn_recv(_sock, &buf, NN_MSG, 0);

                if (rbs < 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                std::string r(buf, rbs);

                std::cout << "received [" << r << "]" << std::endl;

                nn_freemsg(buf);
            }

            if (pfd.revents & NN_POLLOUT) {
                std::cout << "asd" << std::endl;
                if (_queue.empty()) {
                    continue;
                }

                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queueMutex);
                    auto msg = _queue.front();

                    std::cout << "send [" << msg << "]" << std::endl;

                    rc = nn_send(_sock, msg.c_str(), msg.length(), 0);
                    if (rc >= 0) {
                        _queue.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

public:
    Nanomsg() : _sock(0), _server(false), _stop(false), _url("ipc:///tmp/test.ipc") {

    }

    Nanomsg(std::string url, bool server) : _url(std::move(url)), _sock(0), _server(server), _stop(false) {

    }

    void start() {
        _start();
//        _th = std::thread([=]() {
//            _start();
//        });
    }

    void stop() {
        _stop = true;

        if (_th.joinable()) {
            _th.join();
        }
    }

    void send(const std::string& msg) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queueMutex);
            _queue.push(msg);
        }
    }

};

int main() {

    Nanomsg client("ipc:///tmp/test.ipc", false);

    client.start();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing to send and nothing to receive, put your thread to sleep
for a millisecond. Pretty much the only thing you can do in your current design.

If possible you could use [nanomsg next generation (nng)](https://github.com/nanomsg/nng) and give its [asynchronous interface](https://nanomsg.github.io/nng/man/tip/libnng.3#_asynchronous_operations) a chance. Seems you are implementing an asynchronous interface yourself anyways, so why not use nanomsg for that as well? They have all the features of your OS's network API available and thus should be able to provide the best latency without wasting CPU time.

Create an async I/O handle and set a callback with `nng_aio_alloc(3)`. Call `nng_recv_aio(3)` to get notified on reception of data. Don't manage your own 
send queue, use `nng_send_aio(3)` in `void Nanomsg::send()` instead.

Unfortunately *nng* is a separate library and your are using the classic *nanomsg*. I noticed that only mid-writing..

Comment: Yes, **[tag:nanomsg]** got redefined a lot since Martin Sústrik's days into forming **[tag:nng]** and the result shows a limited commercial driving factor and almost none community moving the immense re-design + re-factoring work move forward. Yet an interesting domain, no doubts about that ( even when losing the purity of the Martin's original manuscript :o) and all my fingers are crossed for the bright future of **[tag:nng]** a worthy tool, out of any doubts, just the pitty for the lack of commercial pull and financing the real costs of the process for Garrett D'Amore - all respect to him )